# Track event to Google TagManager inside a ServiceWorker

Tags: service-worker, event-tracking

I'm working on a service-worker (really a firebase cloud-messaging serviceworker like [this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/4d2b64d8dc7f3359ee025df793d26c36f01a347c/messaging/firebase-messaging-sw.js#L38-L49)) and I would like to track each time a user receives a push on Google TagManager.

Any help on how to include the script and send tracks within a SW?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The Service worker runs outside the main thread and does not have
>   access to the Window object, meaning that it cannot access the data
>   layer or the ga command queue to create trackers. In short, the
>   actions of a service worker cannot be tracked using the normal
>   on-page, JavaScript-based tracking snippets. What we can do, however,
>   is configure our service worker to send HTTP hits directly to GA.

Here is a sample code

```
fetch('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    v: 1, // Version Number
    t: eventName, // Hit Type
    ec: eventCategory, // Event Category
    ea: eventAction, // Event Action
    el: 'serviceworker' // Event Label
  })
})
```

If you want to get into more details, I would recommend reading this article. https://builtvisible.com/google-analytics-for-pwas-tracking-offline-behaviour-and-more/